# How do I hide the border of a table in a PowerPoint ppt with Perl and Win32::OLE?

Tags: perl, powerpoint, win32ole

How do we change table style (hide table borders) in PowerPoint through Perl?

something like:

```
$table->Table->Style->NoBorder
```

I am using this code at the start:

```
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft PowerPoint';
$Win32::OLE::Warn = 2; 
use File::Basename;
use Time::Piece;
```

And I get the table like this:

```
my $table = $Slide->Shapes->AddTable(
  $rws, $cls, $item{LEFT}, $item{TOP}, $item{WIDTH}, $item{Hei‌​ght}
);
```

Comment: What module are you using to create your .ppt file?

Comment: I am using this code                                                                                    my $table = $Slide->Shapes->AddTable($rws,$cls,$item{LEFT},$item{TOP},$item{WIDTH},$item{Height});

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add that. Also tell us what module you are using for the powerpoint stuff. Not only the part that does it. There is a `use foo` statement at the top of your program that would say something about PowerPoint.

Comment: !use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
!use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft PowerPoint';
!$Win32::OLE::Warn = 2; 
!use File::Basename;
!use Time::Piece;

Comment: **Please [edit] the question**! It's not possible to read it properly in the comments.

Comment: What is the exclamation mark for?

Comment: its used through Ansys CFX, its written by iron python.. You can ignore that

Comment: In that case, remove it please. It's not valid Perl code.

Comment: Can you add some more code? How do you get `$Slide` and how do you create the presentation? Also, what is in `$item`? If you check https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE#Hints-for-Microsoft-Office-automation you'll see it advises to check the OLE docs and the VisualBasic documentation. Have you looked there?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Programmatically Working with Table Styles in PowerPoint 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Hh273476%28v=Office.14%29.aspx), you might be able to use

```
$table->ApplyStyle('{2D5ABB26-0587-4C30-8999-92F81FD0307C}');
```

That CLSID is may not work for versions other than PP 2010.

Post a short but runnable example if you want to make it easier for others to help you.